# Auto-generated duplicate links don't trim titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments, whitespace

If a question is voted as a duplicate of a question with leading or trailing whitespace in the title, the whitespace isn't trimmed, breaking the auto-generated comment.

[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79738/auto-generated-duplicate-links-dont-trim-titles-test) (10k only)

Comment: The real question is: why aren't question titles trimmed before they get put into the database in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is that titles have leading or trailing spaces at all. I am fixing that now, looks like it's been this way for quite a while. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: Make sure to `TRIM()` existing titles.

Comment: @slaks already done 2 hours ago across every site